# My client needs domain and hosting in separate hosting providers

Tags: wordpress, hosting

My client needs domain in `wordpress` and hosting in `skylark`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of clients need this. and Yes, its possible.

Go to `My Sites → Manage → Domains`, choose the domain you want and select `Name Servers & DNS`.

Make sure Use WordPress.com Name Servers is checked. Also make sure your transferred in domain is set to primary.

You can do this by going to `My Sites → Manage → Domains`, choose the domain you want and then select `Make Primary`.